# Cmake: How to have add_custom_command() run after all project files are built

Tags: build, cmake

Using Cmake v3.8, I need my custom command to run only after my newly built .hex, .map, and .elf files are produced. However, the command is not truly running after all of the *.hex, *.map, and *.elf files are produced. Here is what I have:

```
    add_custom_command(
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND python ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/performCrc32.py
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    OUTPUT  performCrc32.out
    COMMENT "Running CRC32 check..."
)
add_custom_target(
    performCrc32 ALL
    DEPENDS performCrc32.py
    performCrc32.out
)
```

What am I missing, if anything?

Comment: Provide code which creates those `.hex`, `.map` and `.elf` files.

Comment: The .hex, .map, and .elf files are created after the build is complete. I need my custom command to run after the build is entirely complete. I thought adding the qualifier "POST_BUILD" would provide me the necessary timing requirements, however, that is not the case. performCrc32.py runs before  the new .hex, .map, and .elf files are built. "execute_process()" runs during Cmake generation so it also doesn't provide me with what I need.

Answer (score 20):

There is no way for add commands to be executed "after the build is entirely complete".

1. You may add commands to be executed after **specific target** is built:

   ```
   add_custom_command(TARGET <kernel-target> POST_BUILD
       COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/performCrc32.py
       WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
       COMMENT "Running CRC32 check..."
   )
   ```

This would add command to be executed after `<kernel-target>` and all its dependencies will be built. Note on the absence of *OUTPUT* option in this case.

This is preferrable way for *post-build checks*, as a check will be performed every time target is *actually (re)built*.

2. You may bind your custom command to your custom target (as usual), and add **dependencies for the target**:

   ```
   add_custom_command(
       COMMAND python ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/performCrc32.py
       WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
       OUTPUT  performCrc32.out
       COMMENT "Running CRC32 check..."
   )
   add_custom_target(
       performCrc32 ALL
       DEPENDS performCrc32.py
       performCrc32.out
   ) 

   add_dependencies(performCrc32 <hex-targets...> <map-targets> <elf-target>)
   ```

   In this case command will be executed after all dependent targets are built. However, the command will be executed only first build: once *OUTPUT* file will be created, the command won't be executed again.

---

*POST_BUILD* option for `add_custom_command` is applicable only for *TARGET* flow of this command, as described above. I am curious why CMake doesn't emit error for your case, when you use *POST_BUILD* without *TARGET*.

Comment: Option 1) which you described seems to be a viable option. Is "<kernel-target>" merely a full path to the .hex/.map/.elfs? Here is the error I'm getting....     ** CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (add_custom_command):
                    No TARGET
                   '/Users/sami/dev/Github_repo/CalaTWO-
                    NRF52832/build/bin/Release/Target/my_app.hex'
                   has been created in this directory.** However, my_app.hex does exist.

Comment: `<kernel-target>` is a **target**. In CMake *target* is no case a *file*.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your last comment. **<kernel-target>**, to me, seems to be a .hex file or a .bin file, etc. You said "In CMake target is no case a file" -- thus **target** is never a file? Can't **target** simply be a path to existing files?

Comment: `Can't target simply be a path to existing files?` Yes, it cannot. You may have a target named `app` and a file named `app` (in current binary directory), but whenever you use `app` as a *target*, CMake never checks the *file* `app.` In my answer I assume that you have **target** `<kernel-target>` which is created like `add_custom_target(<kernel-target> DEPENDS <elf-file> ...)`. In that case the *target* is assumed to be built when a *file* `<elf-file>` is built. That is why I asked you to provide CMake code, which creates those files - with that code my answer would be *more concrete*.

Comment: In the first suggestion, how do you make `add_custom_command(TARGET ..)` rerun each time the script `performCrc32.py` changes?

Comment: @MaximilianMordig: You need to add dependencies for the target with attached custom command. E.g., when create executable/library target, you could add `performCrc32.py` among its sources. Probably, `target_sources` could be used for the same purposes. Alternatively, you could specify dependency in [LINK_DEPENDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LINK_DEPENDS.html) target's property. Note, that not only your `performCrc32.py` script will be rerun, but complete linking step will be rerun. A command added `add_custom_command(TARGET ..)` cannot be re-run separately from the target.