# CMake makes dyld find libraries under /usr/local/lib instead of actual path in runtime

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, dyld, rpath

**PROBLEM**

I am trying to use irrKlang to play music. The irrKlang files are in my project directory. Building was fine but when I run it it reports `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libikpFLAC.dylib` (A lib that should've been in my project directory) and reason: `image not found`.
I don't understand why it looks for dylibs under `/usr/local/lib/` and how I can change that in CMake (not using otool and install_name_tool)

**CODES**
Here is a simple project to make this happen:

`main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "irrKlang.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    irrklang::ISoundEngine* engine = irrklang::createIrrKlangDevice();

    if (!engine)
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize the engine" << std::endl; // error starting up the engine
    engine->play2D("irrKlang/media/ophelia.mp3", true); // Path referencing error, but this is not the issue here, as the program didn't even make it to Hello World
    return 0;
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(Program)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

message("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
file(GLOB IRRKLANG_LIBS "irrKlang/bin/macosx-gcc/*.dylib")
link_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/irrKlang/bin/macosx-gcc")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} irrKlang/bin/macosx-gcc)
set(IRRKLANG_INCLUDE irrKlang/include)
file(GLOB IRRKLANG_INCLUDE_FILES "${IRRKLANG_INCLUDE}/*.h")
include_directories(${IRRKLANG_INCLUDE})

add_executable(Program main.cpp "${IRRKLANG_INCLUDE_FILES}")
target_link_libraries(Program ${IRRKLANG_LIBS})
target_link_directories(Program PUBLIC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/irrKlang/bin/macosx-gcc")
```

My project has directory `irrKlang` with directory tree:

```
irrKlang
├── bin
│   ├── dotnet-4-64
│   ├── linux-gcc-64
│   ├── macosx-gcc (with .dylib files in it)
│   └── winx64-visualStudio
├── doc (...)
├── examples (...)
├── examples.net (...)
├── include
├── lib
│   └── Winx64-visualStudio
├── media (with some audio files in it)
└── plugins
    └── ikpMP3
        └── decoder
```

**Error**:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libikpFLAC.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/mac/Documents/VSCProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug/Program
  Reason: image not found
```

`OTool` (Libs should have been in my project directory and doesn't have `lib` prefix):

```
/usr/local/lib/libikpFLAC.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libikpMP3.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libirrklang.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 904.4.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1292.0.0)
```

This problem is different than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17703510/11225486). The solution there was to use otool and install_name_tool, but then I have to use it everytime I build it. I am wondering if there's a way to use `CorrectDirectory/foo.dylib` instead of `/usr/local/lib/foo.dylib` inside CMake.

I've also tried [RPath handling](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling) but this does not work, and I need to make it work by not installing but building and running it.
`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(Program)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
# use, i.e. don't skip the full RPATH for the build tree
set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH FALSE)

# when building, don't use the install RPATH already
# (but later on when installing)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)

# the RPATH to be used when installing
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/irrKlang/bin/macosx-gcc")

set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/irrKlang/bin/macosx-gcc")

# don't add the automatically determined parts of the RPATH
# which point to directories outside the build tree to the install RPATH
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH FALSE)

message("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
file(GLOB IRRKLANG_LIBS "irrKlang/bin/macosx-gcc/*.dylib")
message("${IRRKLANG_LIBS}")
link_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/irrKlang/bin/macosx-gcc")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} irrKlang/bin/macosx-gcc)
set(IRRKLANG_INCLUDE irrKlang/include)
file(GLOB IRRKLANG_INCLUDE_FILES "${IRRKLANG_INCLUDE}/*.h")
include_directories("${IRRKLANG_INCLUDE}")

add_executable(Program main.cpp "${IRRKLANG_INCLUDE_FILES}")
target_link_libraries(Program "${IRRKLANG_LIBS}")
target_link_directories(Program PUBLIC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/irrKlang/bin/macosx-gcc")
```

**UPDATE**

Right now what I use to solve this problem is by appending the following lines into `CMakeLists.txt` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44212101/cmake-how-to-have-add-custom-command-run-after-all-project-files-are-built):

```
add_custom_command(TARGET Program POST_BUILD
        COMMAND install_name_tool -change /usr/local/lib/libikpFLAC.dylib ${IRRKLANG_LIBDIR}/ikpFLAC.dylib cmake-build-debug/Program
        COMMAND install_name_tool -change /usr/local/lib/libikpMP3.dylib ${IRRKLANG_LIBDIR}/ikpMP3.dylib cmake-build-debug/Program
        COMMAND install_name_tool -change /usr/local/lib/libirrklang.dylib ${IRRKLANG_LIBDIR}/libirrklang.dylib cmake-build-debug/Program
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        COMMENT "Changing lib paths"
        )
```

But still, I wonder if I can systematically solve this without having to repeat them, since there can be a difference between the name of lib referenced in executable and the name of where it actually is (e.g. `.../libikpMP3.dylib` to `.../ikpMP3.dylib` but `.../libirrklang.dylib` stays the same name.